# Ionic Angular double post issue

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

Im doing project with Ionic + Angular + Codeigniter.
When Im doing auth Login Api, form Angular doing double post

Here is my Login.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" hide-nav-bar="true">
  <ion-content class="login">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
    <form ng-submit="saveConn()">
      <div class="list list-inset">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="config.username">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="config.password">
        </label>
        <button class="button button-full button-assertive" name="button">Masuk</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here is My Controller.js

```
$scope.saveConn = function() {
  $scope.config = {};
  $scope.config.username = this.config.username;
  $scope.config.password = this.config.password;
  $scope.bList = {};

    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: 'Checking server connection...',
        showBackdrop: true
    });

    var config = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://yourcurrentsite.com/panel/Api/Login',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        timeout: 5000,
        data: $scope.config,
    };
    event.preventDefault();
    $http(config).
    then(function(response) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
            if (response.Success == 'true') {
                $location.path("/home");
            } else {
                $ionicLoading.show({
                    template: 'Username atau Password Salah',
                    showBackdrop: true
                });
            }
    });
}
```

And here is my current Codeigniter Api for login :

```
  public function Login()
  {
    $obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    if ($this->Prospect->check_user($obj->username, md5($obj->password)) === TRUE) 
    {
        $response = array(
        'Success' => true,
        'Info' => 'Login Sukses');
    }else
    {
        $response = array(
        'Success' => false,
        'Info' => 'Username atau Password Salah');
    }
    echo $this->json_prefix . json_encode($response);
  }
```

I go to Chrome Console and switch to "Network" and see that Login Api is being called twice, the 1st status is false and 2nd status is success (I enter Username and password CORRECTLY).
[image]

Any help will apreciate.

EDIT

1st raw :
{Success: false, Info: "Username and Password Missmatch", Username: null, Password: null}

2nd raw :
{Success: true, Info: "Login Sukses", Username: "edwin", Password: "caitlin"}

Comment: the content size of the request is different though - are you sure it's the same request? what exactly does it look like 1st vs. 2nd can you post the raw requests please?

Comment: i edited my post @OvidiuDolha